# Using the Leibniz formula for a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would you use the Leibniz formula on the following DE:

$$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+l(l+1)y=0$$

for some constant $l\ge0$ to show that for $n\ge0$,

$$y^\left(n+2\right)(0)=[n(n+1)-l(l+1)]y^\left(n\right)(0)$$

Comment: Could you please tell us what context lead you to ask this question? I would like to see the bigger picture.

Comment: The mention of Leibniz formula is so central to how you posed the Question that it stands in need of clarification.  Are you thinking of the differentiation "under the integral sign" formula, or another formula attributed to Leibniz?

Comment: I see that you are still roaming around the site. I would really appreciate it if you could just give me some context. I am genuinely curious as to why you asked that question.

Comment: There is no context unfortunately. It's a question from a university exercise.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with [Spherical Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions). Anyway, thank for your answer. If it was taken from a book, I would very much like to know what book and page it is. Otherwise, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=y'$ and $t(x)=1-x^2$, then notice how:
$$
(1-x^2)y''(x)-2xy'(x) = (tz)'(x)
$$
Thus, your equation may be written as:
$$
(tz)'(x)+l(l+1)y(x)=0
$$
Then we derive $n$ times:
$$
(tz)^{(n+1)}=-l(l+1)y^{(n)}
$$
And by Leibniz formula (since $t^{(k)}=0$ for $k\geq 3$):
$$
ty^{(n+2)}+(n+1)t'y^{(n+1)}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}t''y^{(n)}=-l(l+1)y
$$

Then, evaluating this expression in zero (given that $t'(x)=-2x$ and $t''(x)=-2$):
$$
y^{(n+2)}(0)=[n(n+1)-l(l+1)]y^{(n)}(0)
$$

It is a shame you do not answer nor give any context. Your question was quite interesting.

Comment: +1 Yep the question is really interesting